# Sudden use of memory report change to 100%

Tags: google-chrome, ram, memory-usage, conky

I'm pasting the commands I've learned on SuperUser/Unix & Linux Stack help.  Is this a common report? I do find that the memory is responsive and available, tho the conky report was reading about 9% after booting and loading only the terminal. Now at the same point, after a few minutes, conky says 98%.

[image]

I was using Firefox, adding extensions that I used on Chrome, when soon I noticed the change. Now the memory meter goes to 100% even before launching Firefox or Chrome. Also I'm curious about the huge reserves made by Chrome browser, and wether or not that is normal. Thank you.

**`$ smem --realmem=16G --system --percent`**

```
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware             2.11%      0.00%      2.11% 
kernel image                  0.00%      0.00%      0.00% 
kernel dynamic memory        85.85%     83.77%      2.08% 
userspace memory              6.94%      1.76%      5.18% 
free memory                   5.10%      5.10%      0.00%
```

> UPDATE: Curious output of 'anonymous'
>
> **`$ smem -wkmr | head -n 10`**
>
> ```
> Map                                       PIDs   AVGPSS      PSS 
> <anonymous>                                 94    13.0M     1.2G 
> [heap]                                      66     4.3M   282.8M 
> /opt/google/chrome/chrome                   27     5.2M   140.1M 
> /dev/nvidiactl                               3    14.6M    43.9M 
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-     7     2.0M    14.0M 
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glco     3     4.1M    12.3M 
> /home/jess/.config/google-chrome/Default     1     8.9M     8.9M 
> /SYSV00000000                                6     1.5M     8.8M 
> /home/jess/.config/google-chrome/PepperF    23   371.0K     8.3M
> ```

**`$ ps auxf | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -n`**

```
0 MB        \_ 
### ... 143 identical lines omitted ... ###
0 MB        COMMAND
0 MB        [kthreadd]
0.105469 MB     /usr/lib/epson-backend/ecbd
0.3125 MB       \_
0.316406 MB     \_
0.777344 MB     /usr/sbin/acpid
0.855469 MB     \_
1.37891 MB      \_
1.47266 MB      /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced
1.57031 MB      /sbin/lvmetad
1.97266 MB      /usr/sbin/atd
2.29297 MB      /usr/sbin/kerneloops
2.38672 MB      /usr/sbin/cpufreqd
2.40234 MB      /usr/sbin/kerneloops
2.59375 MB      /usr/sbin/cron
2.67969 MB      /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
2.95703 MB      \_
### ... skipping 90 lines ... ###
10.8828 MB      /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
11.0391 MB      /usr/bin/whoopsie
11.9883 MB      /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
12.375 MB       /usr/sbin/nmbd
14.1445 MB      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord
14.3398 MB      \_
15.2109 MB      |
15.2969 MB      /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
15.4727 MB      \_
15.7344 MB      /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11
16.2031 MB      |
16.4297 MB      |
16.6094 MB      |
16.8789 MB      /usr/bin/python3
17.2031 MB      \_
17.4102 MB      |
17.4375 MB      /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11
17.543 MB       \_
18.1094 MB      \_
18.1133 MB      |
18.1367 MB      /usr/bin/python3
18.457 MB       |
18.668 MB       /usr/lib/fwupd/fwupd
18.8164 MB      \_
19.043 MB       \_
19.5352 MB      \_
20.3633 MB      \_
20.8047 MB      /usr/sbin/smbd
20.8086 MB      |
22.3086 MB      /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
22.3828 MB      \_
25.9102 MB      \_
26.0078 MB      /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
37.0781 MB      /usr/lib/packagekit/packagekitd
37.8789 MB      \_
39.6094 MB      \_
40.3398 MB      \_
40.5273 MB      |
42.332 MB       \_
43.9883 MB      \_
48.4648 MB      \_
50.5547 MB      \_
51.5938 MB      \_
62.5781 MB      \_
66.8633 MB      |
107.23 MB       \_
204.27 MB       |
231.957 MB      \_
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running a beta Chrome?

Comment: Memory not used to run an app, is used for disk/file cache... and as such... it'll look like memory is close to 100% utilized.

Comment: Oddly, I guess, I wasn't running a Chrome Beta until today. It doesn't seem to hinder performance that the cache is large... somewhere. But that just changed overnight after months of normal behavior.

Comment: Boy it sure looks like a Chrome or Chrome extension problem. I'd uninstall it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped. The answer was something simpler. I had changed the conky script argument, such that resetting, in `.conkyrc`: **`no_buffers = true`** fixed that problem. I mistakenly thought that had something to do with buffering the data used by conky during the interval (?)... thank you.